# C server and client exchange mpz_t values incorrectly

Tags: c, gmp

I'm trying to make a server and a client, written in C, exchange mpz_t values. The programs use the GMP library, and some functions of an elliptic curves library. The problem is that the value the client generates is different than the one the server receives. Do you have any idea why is that happening?

```
int server(){
gmp_randstate_t status;
mpz_t curv[2];
mpz_t p;
mpz_t base_point[2];
mpz_t priv_numb;
mpz_t rec; 
mpz_t key;
int sockfd1, sockfd2;
int clilen;
struct sockaddr_un srv_addr, cl_addr;
char *file="parameters.txt";


gmp_randinit_mt(status);
mpz_init(curv[0]); mpz_init(curv[1]);
mpz_init(p);
mpz_init(base_point[0]); mpz_init(base_point[1]);
mpz_init(priv_numb);
mpz_init(rec); 
mpz_init(key);

mpz_t seed;
long sd;
mpz_init(seed);

srand( (unsigned) getpid());
sd=rand();
mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);

gmp_randseed(status, seed);

mpz_urandomb(priv_numb, status, 8);
gmp_printf("priv_numb %Zd\n", priv_numb);

FILE *keyfd=fopen(file, "r");
gmp_fscanf(keyfd, "%Zd %Zd %Zd %Zd %Zd", curv[0], curv[1], p, base_point[0],base_point[1]);

fclose(keyfd);

gmp_printf("curv[0]: %Zd curv[1]: %Zd base[0]: %Zd\n base[1]: %Zd\n p: %Zd\n", curv[0], curv[1], base_point[0], base_point[1], p);
myzmulmod(key, priv_numb, base_point, p);// key = private*base_point mod p

gmp_printf("key: %Zd\n", key);

sockfd1 = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(!sockfd1) 
    printf("Error opening socket\n");
bzero( &srv_addr, sizeof( srv_addr ) );

srv_addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strcpy( srv_addr.sun_path, UNIXSTR_PATH );
unlink(srv_addr.sun_path);
if(bind(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr))<0) {
    perror("Error on binding\n");
     exit(1);
}

listen(sockfd1,1);
clilen = sizeof(cl_addr);
sockfd2 = accept(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr *)&cl_addr, &clilen);


if(recv(sockfd2, &rec, sizeof(mpz_t),0) <0)
    printf("Could not receive key!!!\n");
else {
    gmp_printf("Received: %Zd \n", rec );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(rec));
}

if(close(sockfd1)<0)
    perror("Error closing sockfd1");
if(close(sockfd2)<0)
    perror("Error closing sockfd2");

gmp_randclear(stat);
mpz_clear(curv[0]); mpz_clear(curv[1]);
mpz_clear(p);
mpz_clear(base_point[0]); mpz_clear(base_point[1]);
mpz_clear(priv_numb);
mpz_clear(key); 
return 0;}



 int client(){
gmp_randstate_t status;
mpz_t curv[2];
mpz_t p;
mpz_t base_point[2];
mpz_t priv_numb;
mpz_t rec; mpz_t key;
int sockfd1;
int clilen;
struct sockaddr_un srv_addr;
char *file="parameters.txt";

gmp_randinit_mt(status);
mpz_init(curv[0]); mpz_init(curv[1]);
mpz_init(p);
mpz_init(base_point[0]); mpz_init(base_point[1]);
mpz_init(priv_numb);
mpz_init(rec);
mpz_init(key); 


FILE *keyfd=fopen(file, "r");
gmp_fscanf(keyfd, "%Zd %Zd %Zd %Zd %Zd", curv[0], curv[1], p, base_point[0],base_point[1]);

fclose(keyfd);

gmp_printf("curv[0]: %Zd curv[1]: %Zd base[0]: %Zd\n base[1]: %Zd\n p: %Zd\n", curv[0], curv[1], base_point[0], base_point[1], p);

mpz_t seed;
long sd;
mpz_init(seed);

srand( (unsigned) getpid());
sd=rand();
mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
gmp_randseed(status, seed);

mpz_urandomb(priv_numb, status, 8);

gmp_printf("priv_numb %Zd\n", priv_numb);
myzmulmod(key, priv_numb, base_point, p);

sockfd1 = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(!sockfd1) 
    printf("Error opening socket\n");
srv_addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strcpy( srv_addr.sun_path, UNIXSTR_PATH );


if(connect(sockfd1, (struct sockaddr *)&srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr)) < 0)
    printf("Connection error!!! \n");

if(send(sockfd1, &key, sizeof(key), 0)<0)
    printf("Could not send public key!! \n");
else
    { 
    printf("I sent %d bytes:", sizeof(key));
    gmp_printf(" %Zd\n", key);
    }

if(close(sockfd1)<0)
    perror("Error closing socket!");

gmp_randclear(status);
mpz_clear(curv[0]); mpz_clear(curv[1]);
mpz_clear(p);
mpz_clear(base_point[0]); mpz_clear(base_point[1]);
mpz_clear(priv_numb);
mpz_clear(key);

return 0;}
```

Comment: `mpz_t` contains pointer to dynamically allocated data - you are not correctly serializing it. Suggest using one of the mpz output functions on `key`

Comment: You mean functions like mpz_out_str?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `mpz_t`s to standard C types using one of the [conversion functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html) before sending them, and then convert them back using an [assignment function](https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers) when you receive them.

You should for maximum portability also convert the C types from host byte order to network byte order before sending them, and then convert them back from network byte order to host byte order when you receive them. You use the [conversion functions in netinet/in.h](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) to do this.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however the assignment function I used in the server doesn't restore the original value that the client produced. I think this might happen because the original mpz_t value is too big, so only a part of it is preserved. It is mentioned in the conversion functions page that this could happen. Is there a way I could avoid that?

Comment: You could convert it to a string with `mpz_get_str()` and send it like that and then convert it back with `mpz_set_str()`.